DynamoDB Hot Paritions Key Prefix and Overloading GSIs
I'm trying to implement a single table design in DynamoDB and I've seen recommendations to use prefixes for partition keys to identify entities. For example, a car's record might have a partition key formatted as CAR#<GUID>.
Does using a static prefix like this lead to a hot partition? Specifically, if I have a large number of records (e.g., 500k cars), will all records with the prefix CAR# end up in the same partition, potentially affecting performance?
Additionally, if I create a Global Secondary Index (GSI) using an entity type as the partition key, would this setup also create a hot partition on that GSI? What is a good alternative to fetching all records of a specific entity without performing a scan operation?
I am concerned that using a consistent prefix for partition keys (like CAR#) could lead to hot partitions when scaled up. I would appreciate any insights or recommendations on best practices for avoiding this issue if it is one, particularly with regard to GSIs as well.
Primary Table



PK
SK (entity)
Attr




CAR#12345
Car
Record for Car 12345


CAR#67890
Car
Record for Car 67890


CAR#11111
Car
Record for Car 11111


TRUCK#22222
Truck
Record for Truck 22222



GSI Table



GSI PK
GSI SK
Description




Car
CAR#12345
GSI Record for Type Car 12345


Truck
TRUCK#22222
GSI Record for Type Truck 22222




While car#guid will not cause a hot partition, your index on car might. Each partition on DynamoDB can handle 1000 WCU and 3000 WCU.
If you need more capacity for you index, you may choose to shard your category types, such as ,CAR#1, CAR#2 etc... assigning each category a random number between 0-N.
N is defined by the throughput you expect per category/1000.

Thanks, this seems to work with my data model. I am now wondering, in order to keep track of the manual sharding, would it be a good idea to use another table or a record in my current table to keep track of the records per shard or perform timely routines to update shards?

If you think it's going to change frequently, then you can set it as an item in your table. But typically once it's set it never changes unless your scale increases significantly.
